# Geofence not calling broadcast receiver even if I enforce the inital trigger

Tags: android, gps, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm trying to build an application with GeoFence. I followed this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

I'm creating a geofence around my coordinates and specifying

```
builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
```

So, when the geofence is created should trigger an ENTER or an EXIT trigger (actually it should be an ENTER as the coordinates are the ones I'm on it).

I put a toast on the broadcastReceiver and also a breakpoint but it didn't fire.

This is my code:

Manifest:

```
<manifest [...]

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        [...]
        <receiver
            android:name=".GeofenceBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent;
    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       
       [Not related stuff and foreground & background location permissions already granted]

        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);

        geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SUCCESFULLY CREATED GEOFENCES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR CREATING GEOFENCES: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }



    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (geofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return geofencePendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
        // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return geofencePendingIntent;
    }


    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
        builder.addGeofences(Collections.singletonList(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId("HOME")

                .setCircularRegion(
                        123.456,
                        -123.456,
                        100000
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                .build()));
        return builder.build();
    }
```

When I start the application I get the "SUCCESFULLY CREATED GEOFENCES" toast, but the intent is never triggered.

If there is a goefence, and I am obviusly inside or outside, I should get an event, i guess, right?

Also, here it is the broadcast receiver:

```
public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent); // There's a breakpoint here
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes
                    .getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "error in broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
       
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "EVENT FIRED:" + (geofenceTransition == 1 ? "ENTERED" : "EXITED"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "NOT ENTER NOR EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: I think the problem was that location was not being updated by the OS. Opening another application such as Google Maps triggered the GPS update and then the event worked...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the expiration duration was 50 seconds. As the [trigger could take upto 2-3 minutes](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#Troubleshooting), geofence was expiring before event triggered.

Check expiration duration is enough.